# (ReactJS-Laravel) JWT Authentication Header (Getting User Information)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, jwt

I'm currently on the page of login, How to get the token information that i need to send it to the header? badly i got error (CORS)

> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/me?token=: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

**Installation:** I already install npm install cors --save

**Target Goal:** How to get the email,name of user who login

I already store the token to the localstorage however I don't know how to get the Bearer of that token, I have here my function

```
componentDidMount()
{

    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/me?token=';

    const headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token 
    }

    axios.post(url,{headers:headers}).
    then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })




}
```

In my Postman (I try to watch youtube and I got this as result in my body)

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "testuser",
        "role": 2,
        "email": "content@gmail.com",
        "created_at": "2018-05-23 15:28:47",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-23 15:28:47",
        "Status": "Active"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- First thing : CORS at your client is a good choice, but I suggest using https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors, it's save your time and make easy to config because you are using Laravel.
- Second thing : `axios.defaults.headers.Authorization` is a good way to add Bearer into your request. Check it out at : https://github.com/axios/axios.